Getting the path of the assets folder in Android
Hi I'm very new to Android development.
I'm attempt to pass my pytorch_lite model through LiteModuleLoader.load(modelPath), I have my model in my app's assets folder. I'm attempting to get the full path of my model in that folder to pass to the method.
I tried using AssetManager but I couldn't find a way to get the asset folder's path.
It seems like there should be a simple solution that i'm missing.

There is no path. Assets are not files on the filesystem of the device. They are entries in an APK file.

Was stuck on this for hours, but of course as soon as I post this I find the solution myself.
It was really simple:
instead of using LiteModuleLoader.load() use AssetManager mgr = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets(); LiteModuleLoader.loadModuleFromAsset(mgr,'yolov8n.ptl');
